# Bootstrap Template for a Dash App

Tags: python, visualization, web-scraping

Where Can I find a Bootstrap Template for a Dash app?

Are there implemented examples? I cannot find nothing about this.

I am building a Dashboard with Dash/Plotly but I want to improve the style of the application.